# How to test onChange for ui-material TextField using Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme

I am new to testing, I cannot figure out how to test the changing value in the TextField component

```
   export const ParentComponent = ({
    question,
    onValueChange
    }: ParentProps) => {

    const [value, setValue] = useState(default);

    const onChange = event => {
    const answer = event.target.value;
    setValue(answer);
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      onValueChange(question);
     }, 500);
    };

return (
    <TextField
      className={classes.textField}
      InputLabelProps={{
        className: classes.color
      }}
      onChange={onChange}
      value={value || ""}
    />);
   };
```

This is what I have so far from other answers I read, not sure how to handle the difference between onValueChange and onChange:

```
describe("ParentComponent", () => {
  let mount;
   
  beforeEach(() => {
    mount = createMount();
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    mount.cleanUp();
  });
  it("renders", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<ParentComponent question={Question} onValueChange={() => {}} />);
    expect(wrapper).not.toBeNull();
  });



 it("Should change value when text is entered", () => {
        const onChange = jest.fn();
        const wrapper = mount(<ParentComponent question={Question} onValueChange={() => {}} />);
        const event = {
          target: {
            value: "This is just for test"
          }
        };
        wrapper.find(TextField).simulate("change", event);
        expect(onChange).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(onChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith("This is just for test");
      });
```

Getting this error:

```
Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()
Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to spy on the `onChange` function:

```
const onChange = jest.spyOn(TextField.prototype, 'onChange');
```

`@material-ui` provides complex components, so I guess you'd test it like this (also note that enzyme's `find()` returns a collection of nodes):

```
wrapper.find(TextField).find('input').at(0).simulate('change', event);
```

Comment: What do you mean with "First, you have to spy on the onChange function". Can please you explain this with some more code?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, of course... Regarding the explanation, I'd say that the enzyme's `spy` is its pretty fundamental concept, and since you've correctly edited my answer, I guess that you already know the fundamentals... Please ask some more concrete questions.

Comment: For me this solution did not work. So I used `jest.spyOn(wrapper.find(TextField).props(), 'onChange')` and it worked.